# How to exclude source fields in search APIs?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kotlin

Elasticsearch [Java High Level REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html)'s [GET API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-get.html) provides a way to control which fields of the `_source` are fetched.

```kotlin
val request = GetRequest(index)
    .id(id)
    .fetchSourceContext(FetchSourceContext(true, includedFields, excludedFields))

elasticClient.get(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
```

How can I achieve this with the [Search APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_search_apis.html)?

For example for the following search request:

```kotlin
val source = SearchSourceBuilder()
source.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
val request = SearchRequest(index)
    .source(source)
elasticClient.search(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer [this from official ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html#_source_filtering),

**This method also accepts an array of one or more wildcard patterns to control which fields get included or excluded in a more fine-grained way:**

**code block**

```
String[] includeFields = new String[] {"title", "innerObject.*"};
String[] excludeFields = new String[] {"user"};
sourceBuilder.fetchSource(includeFields, excludeFields);
```

Simlar to get API which you already mentioned, you can provide an array of 
`includeFields` and `excludeFields` to control fetching of the fields from `_source` fields.

Comment: Jeez. I must have been blind! Thanks a lot!